# Why does it say 'Series' object is not callable when I think that I did everything right

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

data = pd.read_csv("TSLA.csv")
data = data.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(data["Date"].values))

plt.figure(figsize=(12.2, 4.5))
plt.title('Close Price', fontsize = 18)
plt.plot(data['Close'])
plt.xlabel(["Date"], fontsize = 18)
plt.ylabel(["Close"], fontsize = 18)
```

I just wanted to have a nice graph of this data but I got the error on the line ---> plt.plot(data['Close'])

Comment: what is the full traceback?

Comment: Please provide us with the error message.

Comment: Maybe there are spaces after the separators in the `.csv` file like `Date, Close` instead of `Date,Close`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out your code for myself, and it worked. The error that you probably had, occurs if the column `Close` does not exist in the dataframe / csv file.

Could you check if there is a **space** after the separators (e.g. `,` or `;`) in your file?
Removing them should provide you with the correct results.

On a side note, you can also use the plotting functionality of pandas to plot a dataframe. In your example, this could be like:

```
ax = data.plot(y="Close", kind="line", fontsize=18, figsize=(12.2, 4.5))
ax.set_title("Close Price", fontdict={"fontsize":18})
```

Comment: When it ran it on Vs code it worked, i just imported the file differently, because this example was on google colab.